# Можете объяснить данную функцию?

Tags: javascript

Ясно, что при нажатии на ul.tabs__caption происходит событие и что дальше?

```js
(function($) {
$(function() {
  
  $('ul.tabs__caption').on('click', 'li:not(.active)', function() {
    $(this)
      .addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
      .closest('div.tabs').find('div.tabs__content').removeClass('active').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
  });
  
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На `li` у которых отсутсвует класс `.active`, при нажатии, вешается функция, которая:

Первая строка:

- добавляет класс active для нажатого li `.addClass('active')`
- берет остальные элементы, на том же уровне`siblings()` и удаляет у них класс active `.removeClass('active')`

Вторая строка:

- берет ближайший div c классом .tabs `closest('div.tabs')`
- находит в них дивы с классами .tabs__content `find('div.tabs__content')` и удаляет во всех нашедшихся дивах классы active `.removeClass('active')`
- берет элемент с порядковым номером (нумерация с нуля) нажатого li `eq($(this).index())` и добавляет туда класс active `.addClass('active')`

`$(this)` это текущий элемент li (на который нажали)

тоесть фактически происходит переключение класса active в элементах li
и переключение класса active в дивах с учетом нажатого элемента li